# How can Celery configure submodules' loggers?

Tags: python, celery

My understanding is that `@after_setup_logger.connect` is supposed to allow you to attach custom handlers. However, this does not work for me.

```py
@after_setup_logger.connect
def setup_loggers(logger: logging.Logger, *args, **kwargs):
    h = LogCollector()
    logger.addHandler(h)  # or even logger.getLogger().addHandler(h)


@app.task()
def add(x: int, y: int):
    result = x + y
    logger.info(f"Add: {x} + {y} = {result}")
    return result
```

Inside the `add` function, `logger` does not have handlers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `LogCollector()` here? I tried the exact same code with `h = logging.FileHandler('celery.log')` and it works fine, i.e, it is logging both on console and in `celery.log`.

Comment: You are correct. I am unsure what I did wrong originally, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I must've had other incorrect code. What I wrote here is fine and exactly how configuring logging with Celery is works.